# (flutter) conver dart Time (not date) to Duration for Alarm

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

i want to set a daily alarm

but i can't convert the Hours and Minutes to Duration to make the Alarm work on time

so is there any Easy way to implement it

i was thinking in converting the time to DateTime and put the year month day etc etc 
and then compare between them by Datetime.diffrence() method

like this

```
Duration duration = DateTime.now().difference(DateTime(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,hour,minute));
```

but i think there is an easier way

so if someone can guide me :) 
thank u

Comment: what happened when you tried to convert the hours and minutes to duration?

Comment: ah ya .. duration got it for me .. omg i just didnt think about it :D ..can u put it as an answer please .. :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to try and convert the hours and minutes to a duration something like below:

```dart
Duration time = new Duration(hours:2, minutes:3, seconds:2);
```

Comment: well .. it didnt work sorry .. i mean the alarm didnt work .. and i think the reason is .. duration give the alarm the whole hours or minutes .. but the alarm need the duration that should wait until it started .. so how can we fix this ... >> i think we can  subtract this duration from the current time .. or thats wrong ?